# Не могу разобраться с датой

Tags: база-данных

Задание "Определить группы товаров, которые не приобретались в 2005 году"

Правильное решение:

```
SELECT good_type_name
FROM GoodTypes AS NotG
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT DISTINCT good_type_name
    FROM Payments, Goods, GoodTypes
    WHERE good_id=good
        AND good_type_id=type
        AND YEAR(date)=2005
        AND good_type_name=NotG.good_type_name)
```

Мое решение:

```
SELECT good_type_name
FROM GoodTypes
JOIN Goods ON GoodTypes.good_type_id=Goods.type
JOIN Payments ON Goods.good_id=Payments.good
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT good_type_name 
    FROM GoodTypes 
    WHERE YEAR(date)=2005)
```

Что в моей логике не так? что выдает неправильный ответ?

Comment: Без структуры таблиц непонятно к каким полям в какой таблице идут обращения

Answer (score 0):

В вашем решении не хватает связи с внешним запросом:

```
SELECT good_type_name
FROM GoodTypes AS GT
JOIN Goods ON NotG.good_type_id = Goods.type
JOIN Payments ON Goods.good_id = Payments.good
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM GoodTypes 
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2005
        AND good_type_name = GT.good_type_name)
```

Вот этой:

```
AND good_type_name = NotG.good_type_name
```

Соответственно подзапрос выдаёт результат для всех строк. А если результат есть(неважно какой), то NOT EXISTS строку исключает - следовательно все строки будут пропущены и результат окажется пустым.

---

Могу ошибаться на счёт структуры таблиц, т.к. не вижу их, но вот то что отсутствует связь между подзапросом и запросом - это причина ошибки.

Comment: Вы исходите из предположения что у автора в ее запросе указаны верные связи? но в таком случае вы правы и ошибка в принимающей решение системе? мне кажется это слегка более невероятным событием нежели ошибка в связях у автора из за чего решение может быть совершенно не верным :)

Comment: Ну а теперь перейдем к мякотке решение автора - нерабочее, причина проста - выборка данных идет с джоином, но нету group by / distinct что выводит в ответ гораздо больше данных даже при том что это может работать быстрей - это уже не верно. кстати ваше решение тоже нерабочее, можете подумать на досуге, подскажу куда думать - нельзя вот так взять и заменить not in (select x=y) на in ( select x <> y), эти условия в некоторых случаях не тождественны